# How to put some commands into longtable by \AtBeginEnvironment?

Tags: captions, longtable, etoolbox

In my case, I am 100% sure that the second and other captions like "continuation of table N" is the same for all of the tables. So I have reason to put this in all the `longtable`'s:

```
\endfirsthead\caption*{Окончание Таблицы \thetable} \\
\hline
\endhead\hline
\endfoot
```

But when I am trying to do it with `\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{...}`, I get an error I do not understand:

```
Misplaced \crcr.
\LT@echunk ->\crcr 
                   \LT@save@row \cr \egroup \global \setbox \@ne \lastbox \u...
l.6 \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
```

Moreover, commands like `\small` work fine. What's wrong with this code?

Full code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes} % для того чтобы задать нестандартный 14-ый размер шрифта
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{epigraph} % для эпиграфов и продвинутых цитат
\usepackage{csquotes} % ещё одна штука для цитат
\usepackage[unicode,hidelinks]{hyperref} % подключаем hyperref (для ссылок внутри  pdf)
\usepackage[left=30mm, top=15mm, right=10mm, bottom=20mm, nohead, footskip=10mm]{geometry} % настройки поле документа
\usepackage[tableposition=bottom]{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{longtable}

\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\small
\endfirsthead\caption*{Окончание Таблицы \thetable} \\
    \hline
    \endhead\hline
    \endfoot
}

\begin{document}
\section{Тест longtable}
Текст, размером 14pt.
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Ordinarily on this site, questions need an example that people can compile so starting from `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This is so troubleshooting can be easily done. Could you please include a full example of the code, including your document class and relevant packages and commands please?

Comment: Also note that there's a difference (possibly) between the `longtable` and `Longtable` environment. We would need more detail in order to answer your question.

Comment: urelaed to the table but you have `\usepackage{fontspec}` so must be using luatex or xetex so should no have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong. I think you cannot use the `\AtBeginEnvironment` hook to set the `longtable` environment.

See `etoolbox` package P.5:

`\AtBeginEnvironment{<environment>}{<code>}`
Appends arbitrary `code` to a hook executed by the `\begin` command at the beginning of a given `environment`, immediately before `\<environment>`, inside the group
opened by `\begin`.

From my understanding, this means the code will be executed outside the `longtable` environment. So such as `\caption`, `\afterfirsthead` cannot be used at this point.

If you don't want type the same commands over and over again for each `longtable` environment, I think there is a workaround to define a macro with the codes you want to input in your preamble. like this:

```
\newcommand{\ltbsetting}{
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\
\hline\endfirsthead
\caption*{\small Окончание Таблицы \thetable} \\
\hline\endhead
\hline\endfoot
}
```

And use this macro everytime you have a `longtable` environment:

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\ltbsetting
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
...
...
```

Also, you should notice, I put the `\small` in side the `\caption` command. I think that is what you wanted. The caption will be small not the rest of the table.

Comment: I made ```\renewenvironment``` of longtable, so i think this is also the solution. But maybe etoolbox has some command, putting its arguments immediately after ```\begin{...}```?